# C - Solving Magic Square

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a program which checks whether a given matrix is a magic square or not. A magic square is where the sum of all the numbers in each of the sequences vertically, horizontally and diagonally are the same.
Whatever combination of numbers I enter, it always returns Magic Square as true.
Edit: Fixed diagonals (kinda), except it outputs additional info along with the diagonal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <stdbool.h>

int main() 
{
int nRows;
int nCols;
int sumR;
int sumC;
int sumD = 0;
int sumD2 = 0;
int k;
int p;
//bool isMagic = 1;


//Defining Matrix order
printf("Enter number of Rows: \n");
scanf("%i",&nRows);


printf("Enter number of Columns: \n");
scanf("%i",&nCols);

int matrix[nRows][nCols];
//int SumR[nRows];
//sint SumC[nCols];

//Enterring Coefficients of the Matrix
for(k = 0; k < nRows; ++k){
    for(p = 0; p < nCols; ++p){
        printf("Enter value for Matrix[%i][%i]: ",k,p);

        scanf("%i",&matrix[k][p]);
    }
}


//Adding diagonal elements
for(k = 0; k < nRows; ++k){
    //for(p = 0; p < nCols; ++p){
        //if(k == p ){
            sumD = sumD + matrix[k][k];
            sumD2 = sumD2 + matrix[k][nCols - k - 1];
            //sumD2 += matrix[k]
        //}
    //}
    printf("Sum of the Diagonals = %i\n",sumD);
    printf("Sum of the Diagonals2 = %i\n",sumD2);
    //sumD2 = 0;
    //sumD = 0;

}


//Adding the rows
for(k = 0; k < nRows; ++k){
    for(p = 0; p < nCols; ++p){
        sumR += matrix[k][p];
    }
    printf("Sum of the %i row is = %i\n",k,sumR);
    //if(sumR != sumC)
        //isMagic = 0;
    sumR = 0;
}

//Adding the columns
for(p = 0; p < nRows; ++p){
    for(k = 0; k < nCols; ++k){
        sumC += matrix[k][p];
    }
    printf("Sum of the %i column is = %i\n",p,sumC);
    //if(sumC != sumR)
        //isMagic = 0;
    sumC = 0;

}


//Displaying matrix
for(k = 0; k < nRows; ++k){
    for(p = 0; p < nCols; ++p){
    printf("%i\t",matrix[k][p]);
}
printf("\n");
} 



if(sumR == sumC == sumD == sumD2){
    printf("\nMagic Square!\n");
}
else{
    printf("\nNot a Magic Square!\n");
}


return 0;
//col[n]+row[n] == userinput

}
```

Comment: You don't initialize any of your variables.

Comment: The fact that your first `printf` is wrong indicates that you've made absolutely no effort to debug this on your own. BTW, there are two diagonals. And, by definition, a square has an equal number of rows and columns.

Comment: @user3386109 that is why I initially hardcoded it to 2

Comment: @robinhood46 The first diagonal has `k==p`. The second diagonal is slightly harder to figure out. Hint: it starts at `k==0` and `p==nCols-1`.

Comment: @user3386109 is it p == k+1

Comment: @robinhood46 Nope, draw a square on a piece of paper, and write in the coordinates of the second diagonal, and see if you can figure out the pattern.

Comment: @user3386109 okay so I got the diagonals working now. Except it spits out some other output along with the actual diagonals, unsure why

Comment: Yup, that's the correct indexing for `sumD2`. The indexing for `sumD` should be `matrix[k][k]`. That allows you to get rid of the `p` loop. The only other thing is that you need to set `sumD2=0` and `sumD=0` before the loop.

Comment: @user3386109 it prints both diagonals 3 times, the first  2 outputs are incorrect but the 3rd is correct

Comment: The `printfs` are inside the loop, so they print the intermediate results as well as the final result.

Comment: @user3386109 if I move the printfs out of the for loop I get 31 and 21 as the diagonals

Comment: What were they printing when they were inside the loop?

Comment: @user3386109 it works now, I changed the iterator accidentally.

Comment: @user3386109 when I mean works, I mean it correctly adds the diagonals,rows,columns and displays them. Now i need to work on the check to make it whether its magic or not

Comment: Ok, good to hear. Have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I used the isMagic method to solve this, as suggested by @Javier Galan. Here is the complete, working code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
int nRows;
int nCols;
int sumR;
int sumC;
int sumD = 0;
int sumD2 = 0;
int k;
int p;
int isMagic = 1;


//Defining Matrix order
printf("Enter number of Rows: \n");
scanf("%i",&nRows);


printf("Enter number of Columns: \n");
scanf("%i",&nCols);

int matrix[nRows][nCols];

//Enterring Coefficients of the Matrix
for(k = 0; k < nRows; ++k){
    for(p = 0; p < nCols; ++p){
        printf("Enter value for Matrix[%i][%i]: ",k,p);

        scanf("%i",&matrix[k][p]);
    }
}


//Adding diagonal elements
for(k = 0; k < nRows ; ++k){
        sumD += matrix[k][k];
        sumD2 += matrix[k][nCols - k - 1];
}
    printf("Sum of right Diagonal = %i\n",sumD);
    printf("Sum of left Diagonal = %i\n",sumD2);



//Adding the rows
for(k = 0; k < nRows; ++k){
    for(p = 0; p < nCols; ++p){
        sumR += matrix[k][p];
    }
    printf("Sum of the %i row is = %i\n",k,sumR);
        if(sumR != sumD && sumD2)
         isMagic = 0;
    sumR = 0;
}

//Adding the columns
for(p = 0; p < nRows; ++p){
    for(k = 0; k < nCols; ++k){
        sumC += matrix[k][p];
    }
    printf("Sum of the %i column is = %i\n",p,sumC);
        if(sumC != sumD && sumD2)
         isMagic = 0;
    sumC = 0;

}


//Displaying matrix
for(k = 0; k < nRows; ++k){
    for(p = 0; p < nCols; ++p){
    printf("%i\t",matrix[k][p]);
}
printf("\n");
}



if(isMagic){
    printf("\nMagic Square!\n");
}
else{
    printf("\nNot a Magic Square!\n");
}


return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `sumR` and `sumC` to zero at the end of each loop. They both have value zero after the calculations. This is why when you perform your check to see if they're equal, it always returns true.

At the moment that you print the values, they appear correct, but then you set it to zero and you're throwing that value away so you cannot use it again later! You need to store an array of row sums and an array of column sums, so you have one sum for every column and every row. Inrtead of just `int sumR`, use something like`int sumR [nCols];` and similarly for `sumC`

Comment: If I remove the sumR = 0 and SumC = 0, it does not add the rows individually, it adds them altogether.

Comment: Yes of course, so at the moment you print the values appear correct, but then you set it to zero and you're throwing that value away so you cannot use it again later! You need to store an array of row sums and an array of column sums, so you have one sum for every column and every row. Inrtead of just `int sumR`, use something like` int sumR [nRows]; ` and similarly  for `sumC`

Comment: oh okay, so I need to create an array which stores the sums so then I don't have to declare it back to 0?

Comment: Will this affect the way I add the rows/cols?

Comment: Yes, you will need to chaage this line: `sumC += matrix[k][p]` and also the sumR line. I can't give you the answer now, I am on a train and I have to get off soon, so I will be away for a while. See if you can work out what needs to change :)

Comment: Only thing confusing me is the fact that I am unsure of which values to add into the array since its either p,k,nCols/nRows and all return 0

Answer (score 1):

The best way can do this is to assume it is a magic matrix. Definning a new variable

```
int isMagic = 1;
```

You obtain the sum of the diagonal. And put it in sumD.

Then, replace sumR = 0; by

```
if (sumR != sumD ) isMagic = 0;
```

and sumC = 0; by

```
if (sumC != sumD ) isMagic = 0;
```

and magic!

```
if( isMagic) {
    printf("\nMagic Square!\n");
}
else{
    printf("\nNot a Magic Square!\n");}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code:

1- you have the value 2 hardcoded in at some point instead of the number of rows and columns.

2-  sumC and sumR are set back to 0 at the very end of execution

3- why do you have one SumR and one SumC when you have multiple rows and columns?

if you want to store the sum or each row ans sum of each column you would need SumR[nCols]  and SumC[nRows]

Comment: I hardcoded, it as I was only receiving one diagonal value. If i don't set sumC and sumR back to 0 it adds all the rows of the matrix and all the columns of the array

Comment: that is why you want to save the sum of each sumR. that is why you need an array of SumR instead of one variable.